# Copying the entire row from 1 file to another Visual Basic Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I'm creating a macro which would need to Copy rows from workbook1 to workbook2.

workbook1 has a header, so we would copy from the 2 row and beyond.
workbook2 already has 50k rows in it, so we have to paste it at the end of the last row

workbooks 1 and 2 has the same header and formatting, so basically I just need to copy the entire row.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Hi there, could you tell us what have you tried so far?

Comment: I'm new in VB so this is only what i can do, I can't figure out what to put inside the IF condition


For intRowN = 2 To WorksheetNewEntries.UsedRange.Rows.Count


                
                Workbooks("file1.xls").Activate
                Rows(intRowN).EntireRow.Copy
                Workbooks("file2.xls").Activate


If Row is empty paste value from file 1

     
     
End If
        Next
        Next

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
Sub CopyData()
Dim wk1, wk2 As Workbook
Dim row1, row2 As Integer
Dim path1, path2 As String

'turn off screen updating
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'' path of 2 file
path1 = "D:\NSO\Tool\test\1.xlsx"
path2 = "D:\NSO\Tool\test\2.xlsx"

''open 2 workbook
Set wk1 = Workbooks.Open(path1)
Set wk2 = Workbooks.Open(path2)

'Get last row of workbook1 and workbook2
row1 = wk1.Sheets(1).Cells(wk1.Sheets(1).Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
row2 = wk2.Sheets(1).Cells(wk2.Sheets(1).Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

'' copy from workbook1 to workbook2
wk1.Sheets(1).Rows("2:" & row1).Copy Destination:=wk2.Sheets(1).Cells(row2, 1)

'' close and save workbook
wk1.Close
wk2.Close (True)

'turn on screen updating
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

End Sub

Comment: I have used this and i get an application defined or object defined error.

code`
`Sub CopyData()
`
`'Get last row of workbook1 and workbook2
`   intRowN = Existing.Sheets(1).Cells(Existing.Sheets(1).Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
 `   intRowE = NewEntries.Sheets(1).Cells(NewEntries.Sheets(1).Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
`   
`    '' copy from workbook1 to workbook2
`   Existing.Sheets(1).Rows("2:" & intRowN).Copy Destination:=NewEntries.Sheets(1).Cells(intRowE, 1)

Comment: After restarting my macros, it now works. But unfortunately it deleted the existing entries in workbook 2.

Comment: Debug at line 
`intRowE = NewEntries.Sheets(1).Cells(NewEntries.Sheets(1).Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1 `
to see if it get the correct last row. May be you can use other column to find last row
Btw, in your code, it will copy data from Existing to NewEntries, is it the same with your idea?